# setInterval, setTimeout with callback function in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I write an application in Node.js which are going to be engine like as simulator game fg. football match. I want to have "on-line broadcast" and for this reason I created functions like below.
I wonder why my code doesn't work properly. What I'm expecting:

wait

wait

wait

wait

wait

something

wait

wait

wait

wait

wait

something

wait

etc.

but I don't have any idea what's wrong with my code, look at this:

```
getText: function() {
    console.log("something");
},
setDelay: function(callback) {
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        callback();
    },5000);
},
play: function() {
    var that = this;
    setInterval(function(){
        console.log("wait");
        that.setDelay(that.getText);    
    },1000);
},
```

I'm getting something like this:

wait

wait

wait

wait

wait

something

wait

something

wait

something

etc.

any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're calling `setDelay()` every second:

```
getText: function() {
    console.log("something");
},
setDelay: function(callback) {
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        callback();
    }, 5000);
},
play: function() {
    var that = this;
    setInterval(function () {
        console.log("wait");
        that.setDelay(that.getText); // << here
    }, 1000);
},
```

What happens:

> 1s -> setDelay() -> timeout1 is created
>   2s -> setDelay() -> timeout2 is created
>   3s -> setDelay() -> timeout3 is created
>   4s -> setDelay() -> timeout4 is created
>   5s -> setDelay() -> timeout5 is created
>   6s -> setDelay() -> timeout6 is created // timeout1's 5s are done, so it fires
>   7s -> setDelay() -> timeout7 is created // timeout2's 5s are done, so it fires
>   8s -> setDelay() -> timeout8 is created // timeout3's 5s are done, so it fires
>   and so on...

Comment: nothing special. I know about that. Can you explain, why first execute setDelay() causing: wait, wait, wait, wait, wait and something? why it doesn't show straightaway: wait, something, wait, something etc..

Comment: I updated my answer with a little "detail" of what's happenning. Your timeouts are 5s so they all wait 5s before firing, that's why you see "something" only after 5 "wait".

Answer (score 1):

Inside of your `play` function, every second, you're running `that.setDelay`, which then waits five seconds before running `console.log("something");`.

What you could do instead is have two `setInterval`'s running:

```
play: function() {
    var that = this;
    setInterval(function () {
        console.log("wait");
    }, 1000);
    setInterval(function () {
        that.getText();
    }, 5000);
},
```

This way, every second you'll get the output "wait", and every five seconds, the output "something".

Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 1):

I would try to unpick the two intermingled timeouts/intervals and have just one that you clear/reset once you've reached the loop limit. It makes it a little easier to follow. Something like this:

```
function play(count) {
  var count = count || 1;
  var t;
  console.log(count);
  if (count !== 0 && count % 5 === 0) {
    clearTimeout(t);
    console.log('something');
    t = setTimeout(play, 5000, 1);
  } else {
    t = setTimeout(play, 1000, ++count);
  }
}

play();
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/foqzpqr2/1/)

Or, in line with your own code:

```
var obj = {
  delay: 5000,
  timer: 1000,
  getText: function () {
    console.log('something');
  },
  play: function(count) {
    var count = count || 1;
    var t;
    if (count !== 0 && count % 5 === 0) {
      clearTimeout(t);
      this.getText();
      t = setTimeout(this.play.bind(this), this.delay, 1);
    } else {
      t = setTimeout(this.play.bind(this), this.timer, ++count);
    }
  }
}

obj.play();
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/L43ed8va/6/)